# Hiding a Window when capturing screen content using MediaProjection

Tags: android, android-windowmanager

I'm using the [MediaProjection API](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/projection/package-summary.html) to capture screen content. However, my app also uses a non-application window (like a system alert dialog added directly to the `WindowManager`) as an overlay and this is something I want omitted (as if it was invisible) from the screen contents captured.

When I set the window as secure, this results in a black rectangle in place of the window.

Is there any way to capture screen contents as if the overlay window was not there at all?

EDIT: To be clear, I want the overlay window to be visible to the user but not captured.

Answer (score 1):

**Note**: this method require your interested widget to hide/ignore should be 50% transparent (can't be too opaque or transparent) when it is displayed on screen and you need to know shape of your widget as a mask in order to completely hide it transparent on output frame. This wasn't originally my idea and I want to give him/her credit on a similar post which I can't remember now.
Since you have 50% transparency you have 0.5 alpha this is how you widget pixels composite with actual background to produce new screen pixel.

```
resultantPixel(R channel) = widget(R) * 0.5 + background(R) * 0.5,

resultantPixel(G channel) = widget(G) * 0.5 + background(G) * 0.5,

resultantPixel(B channel) = widget(B) * 0.5 + background(B) * 0.5
```

Now when you are done recording pixels you can do **reverse alpha compositing** on each channel, since you already know the pixel values of the widget.you can extract the original background pixel values

```
originalPixel(channel X) = (captuedInputImage(X) - (widget(X) / 2)) * 2
```

But you need to apply this reverse composition only on pixels where widget and background intercept so you need to know shape of your widget as a mask where widget is presented with `#ffffff` and background with `#000000`. Then you can finally blend pixels as,

```
resultFrame = inputCapturedImage | (maskImage & reverseCompositedImage)
```

Thats it! now resultFrame now show your display without your widget as if it is completely invisible.

### So why choose 50% transparency?

Because it is the optimal value to achieve accurate result. If you make widget less transparent like 20% it would be difficult to recreate original background value. Imagine with 50% transparent you have original background channel value of `41` and it will represent as `20` integer when rendered with widget because `(41 * 0.5 ->alpha)` and when apply reverse composition we multiply it again with same alpha factor `20 * 2 = 40`. So you can see we only got `1` pixel value inaccuracy which is ignorable, but if you choose an alpha of `0.1` you will have higher pixel value inaccuracy. Raising above 50% transparency will less to no effect on accuracy  if you do the math and make the widget less visible to actual user, therefore `50%` is optimal value.

#### Example Code snippet

```java
public void restoreBackgroundImage(Bitmap screenShot) {
    @ColorInt int[] screenShotPixels = new int[screenShot.getWidth() * screenShot.getHeight()];
    screenShot.getPixels(screenShotPixels,0,screenShot.getWidth(),0,0,screenShot.getWidth(),screenShot.getHeight());
    for (int i = 0; i < screenShotPixels.length; i++) {
        screenShotPixels[i] = 0xff000000 | (((0x00ffffff & screenShotPixels[i]) - ((0x00ffffff & maskColors[i]) / 2)) * 2);
        screenShot.setPixels(screenShotPixels,0,screenShot.getWidth(),0,0,screenShot.getWidth(),screenShot.getHeight());
    }
}
```

As you can see restored the background pixels under `maskColors` (which in this case your widget colors). I have divde then multiply by 2 as per 0.5 alpha composition. Hope this helps!

Comment: Could show a Java (android) code example please?

Comment: @FLASHCODER I have updated the answer. check the Java snippet code above.
the setPixel method is used to save the new pixel of the frame from MediaProjection

Comment: "*`I have divde then multiply by 2 as per 0.5 alpha composition.`*" And if i want widget 100% opaque, there some possibility to restore background image without widget?

Comment: @FLASHCODER Actually it's hard to do that at least not from this method. Because it's a paradox that the screen is both the output and input device. MediaProjetion cannot separate rendering layers hence you need some amount of visual information about the background pixels, which is what transparency does. You can go as low as 10% transparency which results in +-9 intensity inaccuracy per channel.